# Why does the Holst term not affect gravitational dynamics?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory, instantons

The general first-order Palatini action in four dimensions is given by

$$S[e,\omega]=\frac{1}{2\kappa}\int_{\mathcal{M}} F_{IJ}[\omega]\wedge\left(\star+\frac{1}{\gamma}\right)\left(e^I\wedge e^J\right),$$

where

$$F[\omega]\sim\mathrm{d}\omega+\omega\wedge\omega$$

is the gauge curvature constructed from the spin connection. It is well known that, classically, the $1/\gamma$ term (the Holst term) does not affect gravitational dynamics. This is not too difficult to see simply by deriving the equations of motion of the system -- the constant $\gamma$ can be made to drop out completely (however, the Holst term plays a big role in the quantum theory).

This reminds me deeply of another theory in four-dimensions: Yang-Mills with a topological term. Indeed, the classical dynamics of the Yang-Mills action

$$S[A]=\frac{1}{2g^2_{\text{YM}}}\int_{\mathcal{M}}\text{Tr}\left[F\wedge\left(\star+\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\right)F\right]$$

is completely independent of the value of $\theta$. This is because the $\theta$ term can be written as the derivative of a Chern-Simons term, namely

$$\int_{\mathcal{M}}\text{Tr}\left[F\wedge F\right]=\int_{\mathcal{M}}\mathrm{d}\left(\text{Tr}\left[A\wedge\mathrm{d}A+\frac{2}{3}A\wedge A\wedge A\right]\right),$$

and thus only contributes a boundary term in the action. In fact, this part of the action encodes topological data about the embedding of the gauge group at the boundary $\partial\mathcal{M}$ of the spacetime manifold, and is very important in the classification of instanton solutions.

While it is clear that the Holst term cannot be written as a total derivative off-shell, it doesn't seem unreasonable to me that the Holst term could encode some kind of topological data, similar to that of the $\theta$ term. If not, then my question becomes this: *is there a geometric reason why the Holst term should be completely irrelevant in the classical dynamics of general relativity?*

Comment: Just my 2 cents, in both cases, classically the additional term does not affect the original dynamics, since the Holst term/$\theta$ term differs from the Palatini/YM action only by a Hodge dual. The $\theta$ term being topological is actually **accidental**. A fun exercise: can you construct a similar term for the cosmological constant?

Comment: @MadMax How could one construct a similar term for the cosmological constant? The cosmological constant is $\int_{\mathcal{M}}\star\Lambda$, and "removing" the Hodge dual wouldn't give a top form. You could replace the dual with a constant top form, but since $\Omega^{d}(\mathcal{M})$ is one-dimensional, this would just shift the cosmological constant.

Comment: @MadMax I also have to disagree with the fact that only differing by the presence of the Hodge star not changing the dynamics. The Hodge star, after all, is an operator that depends heavily nontrivially on the metric/tetrad fields.

Comment: Right, you couldn't devise a similar term for the CC. The takeaway is that some characteristics (vanishing or not, topological or not) of these type (Holst/$\theta$) terms shall  be investigated on a case by case basis.

Comment: As for Hodge star, I am following your notation. Generally speaking, these terms can be reformulated schematically as $(1+\gamma^5/\gamma)e^2R$ and $(1 + \gamma^5\theta/2\pi)(e^2F)(e^2F)/e^4$. The differences can be boiled down to a mere $\gamma^5$.

Comment: Here the tetrad $e$ is denoted as $e=e_\mu^a\gamma_adx^{\mu}$. The CC term is $Tr(\gamma^5e^4)$ and the $\gamma^5$ conjugate term $Tr(e^4)$ vanishes identically.